# Getting "Not authorized" error when running SonarQube analysis in Docker container with GitLab Runner

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, gitlab, sonarqube, gitlab-runner

I am trying to run a SonarQube analysis in a Docker container using GitLab Runner, but I'm encountering the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'GlobalServerSettings' defined in org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalServerSettingsProvider: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalServerSettings]: Factory method 'provide' threw exception; nested exception is Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalServerSettings]: Factory method 'provide' threw exception; nested exception is Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

My GitLab Runner is running in a Docker container, and I have SonarQube also running in a Docker container. I've configured my .gitlab-ci.yml file as follows:

```
sonarqube-check:
  tags:
    - my-api
  image:
    name: sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:5.0
    entrypoint: [""]
  variables:
    SONAR_USER_HOME: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"
    GIT_DEPTH: "0"
    SONAR_TOKEN: "$SONARQUBE_TOKEN"
  cache:
    key: "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
    paths:
      - .sonar/cache
  script:
    - sonar-scanner -X 
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'main'
```

My sonar-project.properties file looks like this:

```
sonar.projectKey=my-api
sonar.qualitygate.wait=true
```

I have passed the SonarQube host URL and token as environment variables. Can someone please help me understand what could be causing this "Not authorized" error and how to resolve it?